# How to have a Detailed Membership Report filtered/sorted by pertaining Organization

Tags: civimember, civireport

I have several Organizations

I need a Report which displays the following columns :
Organization, Membership Type, Member (first and last name), email, Phone, Status

I would like this Report sorted by the 3 first columns, and/or filtered by Organization.

How can I ?

Comment: What CMS are you using?  If Drupal, then look at Views

Comment: I use Drupal ; I am aware of Views, but am not sure of its conveniance ; I have to get deeper into it. Can you give me some indications ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally (others will disagree!) I've always found writing CiviCRM Reports to be a horrible Pain In The MySQL!

There are two really easy ways to get what you want:

1) Make a Custom Profile of type "Search Results" then, on advance search, you will see all of these columns side by side, in whichever order and with ability to sort by any column.

2) (If you are a coder or have access to one) build a custom extension! Extensions that retrieve data and display it are really quick to write - one like this would take less than a day. An expert could bang it out in an afternoon.

Comment: 1/ Custom Profile does not seem possible : I need 2 different contacts on the same report line : Organization (or Source ?) and Member (Individual) : I see no way to manage that ; 2/ I am not a coder

Comment: if you add 'current employer' field you can get the Org on a profile too

Answer (score 1):

To build a View you would start with a view based on Contacts. Then add Drupal relationship (under Advanced) to add Contact A to the relationship of 'employee/employer'. Then add fields for eg Display Name (use Relationship to make it the organisation), add display Name, add Membership Type etc. May need to tinker with Filters too.